# How to stop loop partially?

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi

So im writing a basic programme to turn an LED on using a potentiometer, this is my code:

```
def pot():
    import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
    import time
    GPIO.setwarnings(False)
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.IN)
    GPIO.output(4, GPIO.LOW)
    try:
        while True:
            if (GPIO.input(22) == GPIO.HIGH):
                print("switch activated")
                GPIO.output(4, GPIO.HIGH)
                if (GPIO.input(22) == GPIO.LOW):
                   GPIO.output(4, GPIO.LOW) 
            else:
                GPIO.output(4, GPIO.LOW)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        GPIO.cleanup()
pot()
```

When i activate the potentiometer i only want "switch activated" to be printed once but i want the LED to keep running until i deactivate the potentiometer. As the code is "switch activated" will obviously print constantly while the pot is activated. I've tried using a break and other such things but they all either ended the programme or turned off the LED as well. How can i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want the LED to continue glowing, it's as simple as adding another loop. Here's a (slightly) modified version of your code that should work:

```
def pot():
    import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
    import time
    GPIO.setwarnings(False)
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.IN)
    GPIO.output(4, GPIO.LOW)
    try:
        while True:
            if (GPIO.input(22) == GPIO.HIGH):
                print("switch activated")
                # modified part
                while (GPIO.input(22) ==  GPIO.HIGH):
                    GPIO.output(4, GPIO.HIGH)
                # end modification
            else:
                GPIO.output(4, GPIO.LOW)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        GPIO.cleanup()

pot()
```

Another way is to switch on the LED and wait for the input at pin `22` to turn `LOW`. Just change the modified part as below.

```
# modified part
GPIO.output(4, GPIO.HIGH)
while (GPIO.input(22) ==  GPIO.HIGH):
    pass
# end modification
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you want to have the LED react constantly to the signal, but only print the message when the signal changes.

The way to do this is to track the state with a variable.

Note: I'm somewhat confused by the nested GPIO.input calls inside your loop. It seems like these would be redundant, because if the return value of GPIO.input changed, it'd get handled in the next iteration...

```
try:
    state = None

    while True:
        signal = GPIO.input(22)
        GPIO.output(4, signal)

        if signal != state:
            if signal == GPIO.HIGH:
                print("switch activated")
            else:
                print("switch deactivated")
            state = signal

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Answer (score 0):

Outputs can be checked as inputs, too. So you can change your logic to only set the output high if it is currently low.

```
def pot():
    import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
    import time
    GPIO.setwarnings(False)
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.IN)
    GPIO.output(4, GPIO.LOW)
    # Initialize state
    state = GPIO.LOW
    try:
        while True:
            # Set the output high only if the input is high and the output is low
            if (GPIO.input(22) == GPIO.HIGH) and (GPIO.input(4) == GPIO.LOW):
                print("switch activated")
                GPIO.output(4, GPIO.HIGH)
            # If you want, you could do the same here and add a check on the output to 
            # only turn it low if it is currently high
            elif (GPIO.input(22) == GPIO.LOW):
                GPIO.output(4, GPIO.LOW)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        GPIO.cleanup()
pot()
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to move `print("switch activated")` outside the loop if you only want it to be executed once.

Comment: How would I do that, if i only want it to print once the pot is activated?